# While loop boolean confusion

Tags: java, while-loop

Why is my boolean t being set to false after the while loop. I have placed print statements and the "if" conditional within the while loop that sets t=false; never gets hit. Why when I print t out in between the for and while loop does t=false; ?

```
public void addStudents(Student student){
    System.out.println("in addStudents");
    boolean t = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while ( t = true && counter < students.length ){
        // System.out.println("while");
        if (students[counter].equals(student)) {
            // System.out.println("ppppppppppppppppppppppp");
            t = false;
            counter ++;
            // System.out.println("never");
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (t == true) {
        if (students[students.length - 1] != null){
            // System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
            Student[] newstudentsarray = new Student[students.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
                newstudentsarray[i] = students[i];
            }
            students = newstudentsarray;
            students[students.length - 1] = student;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while ( t = true` should probably be `while (t == true`

Comment: `while ( t = true` <- Thats an assignment. You probably meant to write `t==true` or simply `t`. Voting to close because of a typo.

Comment: `t = true` sets `t` to true. You just mean `while(t && counter < students.length)`

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot. Been trying to find that for 1 hour. Thanks guys that really helped.

Comment: You do not need to compare C++ boolean to anything if you use them in a condition: use `myBool` instead of `myBool == true` and `!myBool` instead of `myBool == false`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the [Java Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) where the operator `&&` has a higher precedence as `=`.

So the statement `t = true && counter < students.length` is complied into `t = (true && counter < students.length)` and `t` is alway set to false at the end of the loop.

You probably wanted to write `t == true && counter < students.length` but mistyped `==`.

This is the reason why it's better to write just

```
boolean falsy = false;
if(falsy) {
    System.out.println("This should never happen");
}
if(!falsy) {
    System.out.println("This should always happen");
}
```

Instead of

```
boolean falsy = false;
if(falsy == true) {
    System.out.println("This should never happen");
}
if(falsy == false) {
    System.out.println("This should always happen");
}
```

When you mistyped you got

```
boolean falsy = false;
if(falsy = true) {
    System.out.println("This should never happen."); // This happens
}
if(falsy = false) {
    System.out.println("This should always happen"); // This didn't happens
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know I could do that